# 'Create new book' in Drupal 6 won't create, only shows loading icon

Tags: 6, nodes

Through the admin, Anytime I try to create a new book in Drupal via 'Create Content' > Book page and select '', the loading icon hangs there. When I save the entire page, it creates the page but it doesn't add it to the new book. Going to the list of books does not show the new book either. So, the object isn't being created.

I have feeling this could be a frontend error, but I'm not really sure where to start. I checked the Javascript error console and no errors there, so...

I've attached a screenshot for more context.

I am not going to upgrade to Drupal 7, if someone suggests this.

Maybe there is a way to programmatically create a new book until I figure out what the problem is.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. We had to disable the jQuery update module, but it breaks stuff on the frontpage.